# Ошибка преобразования байт-кода в dex:

Tags: android

Не выводится в APK из за конфликта библиотек, как я думаю. Это произошло 
после того, как я добавил Cloud Messaging в свой проект для отправки 
уведомлений.

build.gradle проекта:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
 belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

**А это Build.gradle модуль** 
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.panda.shop'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.2.jar')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'

    }


android {

    lintOptions {
        disable "ResourceType"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

ошибка:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --output C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\1f\main C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_e1ef8c32d1d939d7e3fab30f385c46ff329880b1.jar C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.2_dbcfed19551d55b26b6970cf46c3edabbeeb25fd.jar C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-24.0.0_67f9b1a339ccfda8dce803824a2522e0d5a0cc24.jar C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_8bc008b6b9c50e51b593fe5de810fdb331f1b341.jar C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-24.0.0_42f6022a482e92d6d27d0c649cebe7f97b44f5ee.jar C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\debug_5cde32ddbf12770f5aa52cc98df985103a92c029.jar C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_405ac2ad8e27b55a556ee701f35a7e46e68d6cf7.jar C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_c7aa0866fa5b054b08b8ba82f02f7c023ba37429.jar C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_84eebed36c2692321c02f2976679070a4fc56ad5.jar C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_e593af53060434725b3827c6c006ff51e468070f.jar C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2_d19105e8baa6b736b3dea9cb70fe352a4f1d759e.jar C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_462b72259f6d5181bc6915c2a98696f3b2888128.jar C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\Parse-1.3.0_b190863964784ccfc98c57037a8d71ff5fa2d908.jar C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\android-support-v4_df099c272c732cc3340ba85d1271159723714f90.jar C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_714484491ee80e73d7f9844d4431dbeec34d7fc9.jar C:\Android\NEW\Android\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\signpost-core-1.2.1.2_dd279100f6b653e04da927a0a1b7c973fa7fc47c.jar}

Comment: Уберите `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')` - `firebase` тянет за собой другую (ещё одну) версию этой библиотеки.

Comment: **Я  пробовал исключать библиотеку**  `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')` 
 **библиотекой**    `appCompact v7....`  **но после этого начинаются конфликты в устаревших методах**  `HttpClient`   **от библиотеки как я предпологаю **  `compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar')`

Comment: Это, по-моему, уже другая проблема: [Apache HTTP Client Removal](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-apache-http-client).

Comment: И targetSdkVersion 22 еще одна проблема. Google Play will require that new apps target at least Android 8.0 (API level 26) from August 1, 2018, and that app updates target Android 8.0 from November 1, 2018.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я последовал этому совету.

> Уберите compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar') - firebase тянет за собой другую (ещё одну) версию этой библиотеки. – woesss

И удалил библиотеку `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')`

А также удалил её из папки lib.

И заменил её на встроенную библиотеку

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'`и проблема решилась.